# Python redis on ready

Tags: python, redis

I have a python application which was written about a year ago, uses redis and has worked flawlessly.

I have just upgraded the system O/S (ARCH) and now, the python script fails to start unless I add a 10 second delay before loading in my initial redis variables.

The log file shows that the last entry is '1.Initialized: REDIS' and the script just appears to quit, I see no errors, it just dies.

Strangely, this was never required previously, and I'm not sure why it is needed now ?!

```
## Initilaize Redis
time.sleep(10)
global rc
rc = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
logger.info('1.Initialized: REDIS')

## Load Globals
global gdata
gdata = rc.hgetall('global')
logger.info('2.Loaded: GLOBALS')
```

Rather than using a fixed delay, is it possible to wait until redis is ready before proceeding with the data retrieval ??

Seems like any attempt to make a redis call before it is alive will result in a crash

I have tried using the ping, but that also terminates the script:

## EDIT - This works

```
## Wait for REDIS LIVE
ping = False
while ping == False:
    try:
      ping = rc.ping()
    except:
      pass
    logger.info(str('Redis Alive:'+str(ping)))
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Could you give more details, how you start your script and in what ways it fails? Is Redis running already or you start it just or two before? I would assume, that you start Redis (as a service) and your python code from the same script and as redis is not completely up, it fails. I your previous installation it is possible, redis was running already being started at boot time.

Comment: Are you sure it is redis specific? It could be a DNS timeout or similar, or firewall blocking. Ofcourse a clear error should be returned, do you have a top level try/except?

Comment: Thanks, the wait for redis live code works, I had a problem with the indent format and the script was not loading. REDIS is running as a service, python script is started by cron @reboot, but I still don't understand why this worked before without the wait !